# Keyboard auto types itself

Tags: windows-7, windows

I’ve got a strange problem. My keyboard keeps typing random keys itself. I’ve tried every possible way that I knew to fix it but nothing works.. I use windows 7 OS. I’ve tried the following.

1. uninstall keyboard drivers n restart
2. scanned the whole system for viruses
3. tried multiple keyboards
4. checked ease of access settings
5. Tried using multiple operating systems
6. restored the system

Comment: Just to be clear: are you saying that this same problem occurs ***with multiple keyboards*** and multiple different operating systems on your computer?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Are keyboards wireless or wired? Try to unplug __everything__  (including mouse) from USB ports except keyboard, try wired keyboard that works for sure on another computer.

Comment: Still the problem exists..

Comment: (1) Does the problem occur also on BIOS settings screen? (2) For a while, try unplugging anything except the monitor and power adapter. Then notice, after unplugging of which device the behavior stops.

Comment: Yes.. Occurs at bios setting too.. And the behavior stops only when I unplug the keyboard..

Comment: @Anha – you said ...*And the behavior stops only when I unplug the keyboard.*  Then, if you plug any different keyboard, will the problem reappear?   (please respond with *@ miroxlav* so I get notified)